# Why are R colours not consistent with the eyedropper tool in Powerpoint?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, powerpoint

Take the bar graph below as an example:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length,)) + geom_bar(stat = "summary", fill = "#2acaea")
```

I am trying to use the colour #2acaea. But when I use the eyedropper tool in Powerpoint on the resulting image, it says the colour is #39D0EE.

Which one is right, and why the difference?

Edit: Looks like exporting the image with `png()` fixes the issue. This problem only applies to the plots as they appear in the R window. Any idea why?

Comment: Are you using the macOS version of PowerPoint? That version has a color managed edit interface. The standard color picker cannot edit the colors accurately.

Comment: @JohnKorchok I am, but it's all working properly now that I'm exporting the images before using the eye dropper rool.

Answer (score 1):

Well, when I do it and upload the image to an online eyedropper - I get #2acaea as expected.

https://imagecolorpicker.com/

SO - I suspect PPT is not respecting the colour palette properly (shocking for an MS product obviously!)

I'm exporting as a PNG from RStudio.  The other possibility would be Your export method breaks it... how did you export?

Comment: Ah okay! When I EXPORT it, the Powerpoint eyedropper hex matches R. It wasn't working when I just ran the code and kept the image in the R console. So I guess there is something funky about that.